# Problem on isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

If $P$ is any point on a straight line drawn through the vertex $A$ of an isosceles triangle $ABC$, parallel to the base, prove that $PB+PC>AB+AC$

Please only give hint and tell how should I start

Comment: What's the set of all points $Q$ such that $QB+QC = AB+AC$?

Comment: Alternatively you can give the points coordinates. Let $A = (x,y)$, $B = (-x,y)$, $C = (0,0)$ and $P = (a,0)$. Express both sides in terms of $x,y,a$, then a lot of rewriting the inequality will yield the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: reflect $B$ with respect to $AP$. Apply triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Extend BA to C’ such that BA = AC’.

Prove that PC = PC’ by showing that AP is the perpendicular bisector of CC’.

Then, apply triangle inequality to $\triangle PBC’$.